# Dot product of matrix and vector without a loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization, dot-product

Suppose we have a Mx3 matrix and a 1x3 vector. How can I compute the dot product of each column and the vector without using a loop?

Comment: Do you mean the dot product of _each row_ and the vector? Otherwise dimensions don't match

Comment: Please give an example with for loop

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly,

```
M = rand(8,3); V = 1:3;
P = sum( M .* V, 2 ); % or in older MATLAB versions: sum( bsxfun(@times, M, V), 2 );
```

If you're dealing with complex numbers, you might have to conjugate one of the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Using Dev-iL’s example data:

```
M = rand(8,3);
V = 1:3;
```

the dot product of each row of `M` with `V` is simply the matrix product with a transposed `V`:

```
M * V'
```

Note that `'` returns the conjugate transpose, which you need for the dot product.

---

Computing the dot product with the *columns* of `M`, as stated in the question, is nonsensical because the dimensions don’t match, hence I presume you meant rows (as the other answers did).